# Necesito obtener una fecha final de una suma de datos - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Tengo una tabla en mysql la cual contiene el id, cantidad del pago mensual, cantidad del pago que ha realizado y fecha en la que realizo el pago, lo que deseo es por ejemplo saber cuando el cliente termino de pagar su primer pago mensual.

Como se muestra en la siguiente imagen, el cliente con el id 2 ha realizado 3 pagos, el primero de 5052 el 12 de Junio, el segundo de 5000 el 30 de Julio y el tercero de 10052 (que es el total de su mensualidad) el 10 de agosto, lo que requiero es obtener la fecha en la que el cliente termino de pagar su primera mensualidad, en este caso debo obtener la del 30 de Julio ya que el cliente termino de pagarlo ese día.

He intentado usar el MAX() o MIN() pero lo unico que obtengo es la fecha minima o la máxima pero no la correcta.

Alguien me podría ayudar por favor!

[image: ¿Ejemplo]

```
select id,total_celular,SUM(pago) as sum_pagos,Max(fecha_pago) as fecha_pago
from pagos_phone group by id having SUM(pago)<total_celular;
```

He intentado con esa consulta pero lo que obtengo es esto....

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado con esta consulta tambien pero al parecer no me regresa la fecha que es [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A tu pregunta le hacen falta detalles, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: ok, ahora comparte por favor que has intentado

Comment: select id,total_celular,SUM(pago) as sum_pagos,Max(fecha_pago) as fecha_pago
from pagos_phone group by id having SUM(pago)<total_celular;   esto es lo que he intentado

Comment: Puedes editar la pregunta y colocar allí los demás detalles

Comment: Listo edite la pregunta

Answer (score 0):

La logica que describes no se puede lograr solo con `group_by`, `max`, etc ya que se basa en completar un total de pago acumulativo (implica sumar pagos hasta lograr un total y comenzar denuevo)

Se pueden usar [variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) donde se acumule la informacion y se vaya marcando los periodos pagados, por ejemplo:

```
select id,total_celular,pago,fecha_pago, 
      if (@last_id<>id,@last_id:=id + @pagado:=0 + @periodo:=0,id) last_id,
      @pagado:=@pagado+pago as pagado,  
      if (@pagado>=total_celular,@periodo:=@periodo+1,@periodo) as periodo_pagado, 
      if(@pagado>=total_celular, @pagado:=total_celular-@pagado, 0) cond
from (select @pagado:=0, @periodo:=0, @last_id:=0 ) t, pagos_phone
ORDER by id, fecha_pago
```

Resultara algo como (no toma en cuenta columnas de procesamiento como `cond` y `last_id`):

```
id  total_celular   pago    fecha_pago  periodo_pagado
1   2450    1000    2020-07-20  0
1   2450    1450    2020-08-27  1
2   10052   5052    2020-06-12  0
2   10052   5000    2020-07-30  1
2   10052   10052   2020-08-10  2
```

Tambien se podria lograr lo mismo agregando una columna `periodo_pagado` y de antemano llenar con el numero de periodo al momento de procesar el pago, evitando hacer este calculo "en vivo".

Luego puedes realizar la consulta que deseas sobre esta informacion:

```
SELECT
id,total_celular, pago, periodo_pagado, max(fecha_pago) ultimo_pago
FROM (
 select id,total_celular,pago,fecha_pago, 
  if (@last_id<>id,@last_id:=id + @pagado:=0 + @periodo:=0,id) last_id,
  @pagado:=@pagado+pago as pagado,  
  if (@pagado>=total_celular,@periodo:=@periodo+1,@periodo) as periodo_pagado, 
  if(@pagado>=total_celular, @pagado:=total_celular-@pagado, 0) cond
 from (select @pagado:=0, @periodo:=0, @last_id:=0 ) t, pagos_phone
 ORDER by id, fecha_pago
) t
WHERE periodo_pagado>0 /* o periodo_pagado=1 si buscas el primero */
GROUP BY id, periodo_pagado
```

El resultado sera por periodo pagado, la ultima fecha

```
id  total_celular   pago    periodo_pagado  ultimo_pago
1   2450    1450    1   2020-08-27
2   10052   5000    1   2020-07-30
2   10052   10052   2   2020-08-10
```